# Slider (on/off) style component similar to iPad

Tags: delphi

Anyone knows of a On/off Delphi component similar to the slider control found on the iPad?

TAdvSmoothSlider (http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advsmoothslider.asp) is the only one I found so far, but I would prefer not to have to purchase/install the entire TMS Smooth Controls Pack.

Anyone knows of a similar component? I already have On/Off images in png format so a component based on png images would also work.

Thanks in advance for any replies/ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could you do with something like this?

```
unit OnOffSwitch;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, Windows, Messages, Graphics, Themes;

type
  TOnOffSwitch = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FMouseHover: Boolean;
    FOff: Boolean;
    FSliderRect: TRect;
    procedure SetMouseHover(Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetOff(Value: Boolean);
    procedure UpdateSliderRect;
    procedure WMWindowPosChanged(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanged);
      message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED;
    procedure CMEnabledChanged(var Message: TMessage);
      message CM_ENABLEDCHANGED;
    procedure CMFocusChanged(var Message: TCMFocusChanged);
      message CM_FOCUSCHANGED;
    procedure CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
  protected
    procedure KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
      X, Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); override;
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property Anchors;
    property Constraints;
    property DragCursor;
    property DragKind;
    property DragMode;
    property Enabled;
    property Font;
    property Off: Boolean read FOff write SetOff default True;
    property OnClick;
    property OnContextPopup;
    property OnDblClick;
    property OnDragDrop;
    property OnDragOver;
    property OnEndDock;
    property OnEndDrag;
    property OnEnter;
    property OnExit;
    property OnKeyDown;
    property OnKeyPress;
    property OnKeyUp;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseUp;
    property OnStartDock;
    property OnStartDrag;
    property ParentFont default False;
    property ParentShowHint;
    property PopupMenu;
    property ShowHint;
    property TabOrder;
    property TabStop default True;
    property Visible;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TOnOffSwitch]);
end;

{ TOnOffSwitch }

resourcestring
  SOff = 'OFF';
  SOn = 'ON';

procedure TOnOffSwitch.CMEnabledChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Invalidate;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TOnOffSwitch.CMFocusChanged(var Message: TCMFocusChanged);
begin
  Invalidate;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TOnOffSwitch.CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  SetMouseHover(False);
  inherited;
end;

constructor TOnOffSwitch.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := [csCaptureMouse, csClickEvents, csDoubleClicks, csOpaque];
  FOff := True;
  Caption := SOff;
  Width := 75;
  Height := 25;
  TabStop := True;
  Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
  Font.Style := [fsBold];
end;

procedure TOnOffSwitch.KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_SPACE then
    SetOff(not FOff);
  inherited KeyUp(Key, Shift);
end;

procedure TOnOffSwitch.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if (Shift = [ssLeft]) and PtInRect(FSliderRect, Point(X, Y)) then
    SetOff(not FOff);
  inherited MouseDown(Button, Shift, X, Y);
end;

procedure TOnOffSwitch.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if GetCaptureControl = nil then
    SetMouseHover(PtInRect(FSliderRect, Point(X, Y)));
  inherited MouseMove(Shift, X, Y);
end;

procedure TOnOffSwitch.Paint;
var
  Button: TThemedButton;
  PaintRect: TRect;
  Details: TThemedElementDetails;
begin
  if ThemeServices.ThemesAvailable then
  begin
    if not Enabled then
      Button := tbPushButtonDisabled
    else if not FOff then
      Button := tbPushButtonPressed
    else
      Button := tbPushButtonNormal;
    PaintRect := ClientRect;
    Details := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(Button);
    ThemeServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, Details, PaintRect);
    if FOff then
      Inc(PaintRect.Left, Round(2 / 5 * Width))
    else
      Dec(PaintRect.Right, Round(2 / 5 * Width));
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Canvas.Font := Self.Font;
    if not Enabled then
      Canvas.Font.Color := $00A0A0A0
    else
      Canvas.Font.Color := $00555555;
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Caption), -1, PaintRect, DT_CENTER or
      DT_VCENTER or DT_SINGLELINE);
    if Enabled and not FOff then
    begin
      OffsetRect(PaintRect, 0, 1);
      Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
      DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Caption), -1, PaintRect, DT_CENTER or
        DT_VCENTER or DT_SINGLELINE);
    end;
    if not Enabled then
      Button := tbPushButtonDisabled
    else if Focused then
      Button := tbPushButtonDefaulted
    else if FMouseHover then
      Button := tbPushButtonHot
    else
      Button := tbPushButtonNormal;
    PaintRect := FSliderRect;
    Details := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(Button);
    ThemeServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, Details, PaintRect);
    if Focused then
    begin
      PaintRect := ThemeServices.ContentRect(Canvas.Handle, Details, PaintRect);
      SetTextColor(Canvas.Handle, clWhite);
      DrawFocusRect(Canvas.Handle, PaintRect);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TOnOffSwitch.SetMouseHover(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FMouseHover <> Value then
  begin
    FMouseHover := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TOnOffSwitch.SetOff(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FOff <> Value then
  begin
    FOff := Value;
    if FOff then
      Caption := SOff
    else
      Caption := SOn;
    UpdateSliderRect;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TOnOffSwitch.UpdateSliderRect;
begin
  if FOff then
    SetRect(FSliderRect, 0, 0, Round(2 / 5 * Width), Height)
  else
    SetRect(FSliderRect, Round(3 / 5 * Width), 0, Width, Height);
end;

procedure TOnOffSwitch.WMWindowPosChanged(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanged);
begin
  inherited;
  UpdateSliderRect;
  Font.Size := Round(Height div 3) + 1;
end;

end.
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the component code, it does everything I need! Have you created the component specifically to answer this question or was it something you already had created in the past?

Comment: Hey, glad I could help. I liked answering your question, but coding is also a kind of training exercise.

Comment: @NGLN Hi, would you please give me an example on how to implement this into form ?

Comment: @Bianca You have to add this unit to a design time package and to install that package in the IDE. For Delphi 7, the appropriate files are [here](https://svn.apada.nl/svn/NLDelphi-opensource/ngln/NLDOnOffSwitch/). For other versions, the files could work too.

Comment: @NGLN THANK YOU! Very appreciate this. Keep up the good work, mate!

Comment: @EASI That's a pity. I don't have XE6. You can probably fix it yourself. Please edit the answer when done.

Comment: Great job! just wanted such control for myself :) You should call `ThemeServices.DrawParentBackground(Handle, Canvas.Handle, @Details, True, @PaintRect);` before the first `ThemeServices.DrawElement(...)` to avoid that dark rectangular border effect when clicking a few times.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, TMS Smooth Pack is available to registered Delphi users for free, so you should be able to get it and use its TAdvSmoothSlider in your apps for free too.

Comment: TMS Smooth Pack is only available to registered users of certain Delphi versions (IIRC, D2010 and XE), which should be mentioned in your answer. (Particularly since the OP didn't mention anything about which version of Delphi is being used.) Also, wouldn't this be more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: Indeed, I do have a registered version of D2010 but since TMS Smooth Pack that is available on Embarcadero web site does not include source-code, I decided against using it. I've had tons of problems in the past because I didn't had the source-code of some components when I tried migrating to newer versions of Delphi.